# Show only one variaton in catalog on meta key

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, variables

Hello i have too much products with variations. I need display only one variations if enable. Catalog display data via taxonomy.php and basic loop. How i can show only one variations but in filter i need show all variatons if selected

Thank you